# Downloading files with curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, download

I have a script which logs into Pacer.gov and then displays links to the several bankruptcy courts electronic case filing systems.

I have a separate set of scripts which handles the raw-data text files we download from these systems, but they have to be uploaded first to my application.

Instead of all this downloading and uploading, I was wondering if it would be at all possible to somehow have my PHP intercept this download?

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around cURL.

Comment: So , What you have try ?

Comment: i have no code to show. i am asking for a starting point. i googled and found nothing. that's why i'm here.

Comment: You dont try anything . What is this ? https://www.google.co.in/search?q=downloading+files+with+curl+-+php&aq=f&oq=downloading+files+with+curl+-+php&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: do you want to download files through a URL or FTP or what ?

Comment: that's the thing, i don't want to download them to the end-user, i want my sever to downlad them so i can plug them into my other script.

Comment: @Adelphia still the same question, do you want to download them via http or ftp or other protocol ?

Comment: http. not trying to get too fancy.

Comment: Please explain problem more clearly, what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what is your problem. If you just don't know how to use CURL - here you have example:

```
$oCurl = curl_init(); // initialize curl object

$url = 'http://domain.com/page';

curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set URL

$siteContent = curl_exec($oCurl); // you will get HTML or other file contents here
```